# Customer Portal - Knowledge : "Internal Server Error"

Tags: customer-portal, knowledge, customer-community, gack

I am trying to set up Knowledge in a Customer Portal, but every time I search for an article I get "An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 1797483391-1440291 (-1880065560)". 
I have reported to SFDC, without any luck.

Does anyone have a workaround for this bug ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MALFORMED_SEARCH: Invalid
language code. Check that the language is included in your Knowledge
language settings. at
.(serviceComponent://ui.aura.components.self.service.model.TopicArticleListModel.m:1)

aura://ComponentController/ACTION$getComponent error: aura://ComponentController: org.auraframework.throwable.AuraExecutionException: TopicArticleListModel: Error creating bean with name topicArticleListModel: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is ui.services.exceptions.ServiceExceptionImpl:

MALFORMED_SEARCH: Invalid language code. Check that the language is included in your Knowledge language settings.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I cant fix it, but I think the solution is in that way

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Site.Urlrewriter, the request url might be getting picked up and altered. If this is the cause, you will need to write code in the mapRequestUrl method to match the url pattern and let it pass through unchanged.